p-norm minimization for single variable
When is there a closed form solution for $$\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \|x u - v\|_p, \quad u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n?$$
More generally, if there is no closed form solution, how can this be solved numerically for different $p$?
For $p=2$ the solution is $x= \frac{u^Tv}{u^Tu}$. For $p=2k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ one gets:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{2k} (-1)^r\left({2k \choose r} \sum_{i=1}^n u^r_i v^{2k-r}_i\right)x^r  = 0.$$
This is still analytically solvable for $p=4$, since it is a quartic, but beyond that I think one needs a numerical root finder.
In the $p=\infty$ case I believe we want to balance things such that $|xu_i - v_i| = |xu_j - v_j|$.
In the $p=1$ case I guess this could be framed as a linear programming problem by introducing artificial variables. I have no idea what to do about other $p$  values.
Edit:
I guess I could take the subdifferential:
$$\partial\|xu-v\|_1 = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x)u_i\,:\,g_i(x) \in \begin{cases} 1, & x u_i - v_i > 0, \\ -1, & x u_i - v_i < 0, \\ [-1, 1], & xu_i = v_i\end{cases} \right\}.$$
Let $u_1, \ldots, u_k < 0$, $u_{k+1}, \ldots, u_{k+z} = 0$, and $u_{k+z+1}, \ldots, u_n$. We can ignore all zero elements from the above. So suppose $u_1, \ldots, u_k<0<u_{k+1}, \ldots, u_n$.
For $i\leq k$ and $x > v_i/u_i$ we have $g_i(x) = -1$, and for $i>k$ and $x<v_i/u_i$ we have $g_i(x) = -1$. So the position of $x$ wrt $v_i/u_i$ determines how many positive and negative terms we have.
For simplicity let $u_i>0$ and let the indexing be such that $v_i/u_i$ is sorted in ascending order. Then $$\partial_x \|xu-v\|_1 = -\sum_{i=1}^r u_i + \sum_{j=r+1}^n u_j, \quad v_r/u_r < x < v_{r+1}/u_{r+1}.$$
Once we find the interval $[v_{r^*}/u_{r^*}, v_{r^*+1}/u_{r^*+1}]$ where the subdifferential is closest to $0$, we can set $x^*\in [v_{r^*}/u_{r^*}, v_{r^*+1}/u_{r^*+1}]$ if the subdifferential is zero on the interior, otherwise we need that $x^*$ is one of the two ends of the interval depending on which sum was larger.
I still need to think a bit about the $u_i<0$ case.
As for $p>1$ I guess I have $d_x|x u_i - v_i|^p = p g_i(x) |xu_i - v_i|^{p-1} u_i.$ I have no idea how to solve the latter in general.

I am not aware of a closed form solution for any $p$.
Yet, utilizing the Iterative Reweighted Least Squares you may build a solver which is efficient and parameterized by $p$.
For the given problem it will become a fast Fixed Point iteration where each iteration has a closed form solution.

I am aware of IRLS. I was hoping for some more formal analysis, e.g., like the thing above  I have for $L_1$. I suppose there ought to be an algorithm for $L_{\infty}$ even if I did not figure it out above. And based on the $p=4$ case, I suspect that something could be done for $p=3$.
